# Загрузка по ссылке html

Tags: html

Я видел на сайтах, что можно при клике по ссылке загрузить любой файл. Как загрузить документ word при клике по ссылке на сайте? Вот мой код:

```
<a class="top" href="">Скачать
```

Comment: Вы можете просто добавить в элемент параметр `download`. Пример: `<a class="top" href="help25.php" download>Скачать</a>` Где файл `help25.php` это файл или ссылка на файл(В Вашем случае word), который необходимо скачать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто нужно добавить в тег ссылки download и прописать ссылку на сам документ word из папки, вот так:

```
<a class="top" href="word.doc" download>Скачать</a>
```